# Extracting number from extracted text in an image using ocr in power automate flow

Tags: power-automate, powerapps

I have an image that is in the format:

```
Siddharth 
DOB : 12/23/2343
Male

1435 4566 7467
```

Now, how can I extract that 12 digit number alone from that extracted text which I extracted using computer vision OCR to text action? Please help.

Take a sample ID card and show how to extract that the ID is not alone which is in the same format as mine. Please it is very important.

Comment: So, where is your data = the result from OCR stored? In a text file? In a variable?